# Copy and paste is unwantedly changes size of objects Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

I'm currently having a problem with Inkscape:

Every time I try to Copy&Paste an Object (e.g. Rectangle) its size changes.

Example: I select a rectangle with size 12x12px and copy it using Ctrl-C/V
its size changes to 14.4x14.4px. See picture below.

This never occured so far and if I'm using duplicate (Ctrl-D)
it also does not occur. Does anyone have an idea what is causing this
behavior? Maybe I accidentialy changed some settings?

[image]

Comment: Both rectangles shown are 12x12px. The selection border is wider. Are you using Filter Effects?

Comment: Yes... indeed: It seems that implicitly added effects when changing the screen appearance of my layers. I find this behavior annoying: Though the rectangle is still 12px wide the size in the menu bar is stated being 14.4px.